# What is the function/class member can I use in SFML 2.5.1 to load glad

Tags: c++, sfml, opengl-3, glad

How would I initialize glad in a SFML 2.5.1 app? Is there a function or class member to do that?
I am following [learnopengl's](https://learnopengl.com) tutorials (but this time with SFML, instead of GLFW)

Edit:

To clarify, I mean that with glad and GLFW, you use
`gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)`

to load the function to load OpenGL. Is there a SFML 2.5.1 function for this, or will I have to write my own?

Answer (score 0):

Using SFML 2.5.1 the following worked for me:

```
gladLoadGLLoader(reinterpret_cast<GLADloadproc>(sf::Context::getFunction))
```

Some more info here:
https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Context.php